# Conditions where backbiting isn't considered as a sin? Is giving -ve feed back of employees to higher authority is considered as sin- Backbiting?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, backbiting

My questions say all

Is giving -ve feed back of employees under you to higher authority is considered as sin- Backbiting (Gheebat).

or reporting -ve feed back of your co-worker but whatever you are saying is true to higher authority is considered as backbiting and sinful.

without the intention of any politics .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assalamualaikum wr wb

There are 6 cases in which you can talk about a person in their absence.

1. Complaining (feedback) to a person of authority.
2. Seeking help in changing an evil and turning evils to that which is correct: An example of this is if someone witnesses a person drinking alcohol and then he mentions that to his guardian seeking to correct him and assist in prohibiting evil.
3. Seeking a religious ruling (fatwa)
4. Warning the Muslim ummah
5. Of an evil being committed openly by someone
6. For identification of person who is known by a nickname.

The first two will fall into your category.

Hope this helps and Allah knows best.

Sources: Riyaadh-us-Saaliheen, chapter 256

Comment: I've seen people down voting without leaving a single comment for their reason to down vote. Do you have a reason, please share so i can improve my answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answer but it would be nice if you could add valid source for  authenticity.

Comment: this? http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/1/256